# NextJS NGINX config when using custom basePath

Tags: javascript, nginx, next.js, config

I'm running two seperate NextJS projects under the same domain. One, the base, under port 3000, and the new one under port 3025.

I'm aware that the official [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/basePath) recommends the following when setting up your NGINX config for hot-reloading:

```
        location /_next/webpack-hmr {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/_next/webpack-hmr;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

        location /_next/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }

        location /__nextjs_original-stack-frame {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }
```

However, if I use a custom basePath, i.e. `/test` under my `next.config.js`, is there a different process I should use?

I've tried the below, with it working for my existing project but no luck with my new one.

```
        location /test/_next/webpack-hmr {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3025/test/_next/webpack-hmr;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

        location /test/_next/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3025;
        }

        location /test/__nextjs_original-stack-frame {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3025;
        }

        location /_next/webpack-hmr {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/_next/webpack-hmr;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

        location /_next/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }

        location /__nextjs_original-stack-frame {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }
```

HTML pages route fine through my new project, but the hot reloading web socket doesn't.